# Box shadow: hide top shadow

Tags: html, css

I've read like 10 questions here and could not apply them to my situation.

I've created the example here

http://jsfiddle.net/Y4uHm/4/

I need to hide the shadow on the top side of the content box.
I am not sure if I am doing it right or I should tailor image in some other way.
I believe it can be done in some more smart way than using background to create side shadows.
Thanks.

To satisfy the rules:

HTML code

```
<div class="container-wrapper">
   blahblah header is here
 </div>
 <div class="container-wrapper breadcrumbz">
   <div class="pusher"></div> <!-- only for experiment. i know about margins and paddings :) -->
   <div class="content">
      There should be no shadow on top of this block
   </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: #4ca8cb;
}
.container-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 500px;
    padding:0 50px;
}

.breadcrumbz {
   background: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14562883/shadowline.png') no-repeat top center;
}
.pusher {
    height: 14px;
}
.content {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px #555;
    background-color: #e7eaeb;
    height: 200px;
}
```

**Update**

I've solved that.
The solution is need to be improved but I got the method.

I can move the bottom block "under" using

```
position:relative
```

and negative margin

http://jsfiddle.net/Y4uHm/7/

Comment: Are you just trying to hide the shadows to the *side* of the content box, or the shadow directly above it?

Comment: like this: http://jsfiddle.net/QY8vb/?

Comment: @RazeelAkbar that wont affect the box shadow of `.content`

Comment: @stackErr I've tried this, but there is still a line and it is noticeable :-/
If I push the shadow even further down to remove the line, then a user can see a gap in side shadows

Comment: @Adrift take a look at js fiddle. There is an img on the top and white block underneath with box-shadow. I need to glue them seamless.

Comment: try using this to get what you want/need: http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/

Answer (score 1):

you can use `:before` pseudoelement

```
        .content {
            background-color: #e7eaeb;
            height: 200px;
            position: relative;
        }
        .content::before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 198px;
            background-color: transparent;
            z-index: -1;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px black;
            top: 2px;
        }
```